# postgresql - randomly inserting rows from one table to another while checking that conditions are met

Tags: postgresql

I have a tableA that contains an id, a weight (int), and other category fields which I have to filter. The lower the weight, the highest the probability of being copied to tableB.

I have to copy a certain amount of rows (125) and I have to make sure that certain conditions are met in tableB:

- at least 5 rows with `fieldA = 'value1' and fieldB = 'value10'`
- at least 5 rows with `fieldA = 'value1' and fieldB = 'value11'`
- at least 1 row `fieldA = 'value2'`
- also other conditions that are more or less the same.

Selecting the rows is not really a problem:

```sql
insert into tableB (id, weight, fieldA, fieldB)
select id, weight, fieldA, fieldB
from tableA
where 
    (fieldA = 'value1' and fieldB = 'value10')
    or (fieldA = 'value1' and fieldB = 'value11')
    or (fieldA = 'value2')
order by random() * weight
```

But since tableB is filled with "random" values, how can I make sure that the minimum conditions are met? Do I need to do this in a loop? My guess is yes: insert one row, check conditions, then insert another row, check conditions, and so on. Never done a loop in SQL before, some guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd use a `UNION` of multiple queries, one per condition, each with the respective `limit`, and then another query for rows matching any condition from which you take the remaining amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROW_NUMBER`with some additional logic is your friend.

Here the outlook

- define for each your condition (e.g. `fieldA = 'value1' and fieldB = 'value10'`) a *unique* `thread_id`
- define for each *thread* a `row_number` with respect of the descending `weight` - i.e. `partition by thread_id order by weight desc`
- keep the `row_number` only for the required minimal number (e.g. 5 for the thread above)
- select all rows with `row_number` and additional rows to your limit orderen on descending `weight` - `order by rn nulls last, weight desc`

Of course it will work only if the if the table has the required minimal count of the rows for each thread and if the sum of the minimal count is less than your overall limit...

**Query**

```
with ta as (
select 
 a.*,
 case /* your conditions here */
 when fieldA = 'value1' and fieldB = 'value10' then 1
 when fieldA = 'value1' and fieldB = 'value11' then 2
 when fieldA = 'value2' then 3
 end as thread_id
from tableA a
), ta2 as (
select 
 ta.*,  /* add index rn for each thread */
 row_number ()  over (partition by thread_id order by weight desc) rn
from ta
)
select 
  id, fielda, fieldb, weight, thread_id,
  case /* keep rn for the required counts */
  when thread_id in (1,2) and rn <= 5 or 
       thread_id = 3 and rn <= 1 
  then rn   end as rn
from ta2
order by 6 nulls last, weight desc 
limit 125
```

**Sample Data**

```
create table tableA as
select 
id,
'value'|| floor(random() * 12 + 1)::text as fieldA,
'value'|| floor(random() * 12 + 1)::text as fieldb,
random() weight
from generate_series(1,100000) t(id)
```

**Result**

```
id   |fielda |fieldb |weight            |thread_id|rn|
-----+-------+-------+------------------+---------+--+
75078|value2 |value5 | 0.999945197714716|        3| 1|
69603|value1 |value10|0.9981664255434559|        1| 1|
90845|value1 |value11|0.9961481124707383|        2| 1|
98661|value1 |value10| 0.995685359324316|        1| 2|
73730|value1 |value11|0.9943281590439526|        2| 2|
20895|value1 |value10|0.9948395132030576|        1| 3|
28411|value1 |value11|0.9926846343501374|        2| 3|
 6689|value1 |value10|0.9926810486253324|        1| 4|
26683|value1 |value11|0.9896049495594461|        2| 4|
52026|value1 |value10|0.9915162874600227|        1| 5|
48511|value1 |value11|0.9881885052326673|        2| 5|
42838|value8 |value2 |0.9999986646619519|         |  |
93206|value3 |value12|0.9999955774933724|         |  |
39188|value8 |value8 |0.9999941396240928|         |  |
54205|value7 |value8 | 0.999971846101122|         |  |
...
```

Comment: This is great! I guess my only concern with this solution is that all the rows are selected sequentially based on their weight rather then being randomly selected based on their weight. Or I've misunderstood the solution!

Comment: @mikibok Not sure what you mean exactly with *randomly selected based on their weight*, but you can of course replace in two place where I `order by weight` with `order by random() * weight` - if it is that what you mean (leave the `desc` of course)

Comment: Yes of course! Useful in the window function. Thank you, it's a great solution! Combining the thread_id and `order by ... nulls last` is really where the magic happens and what I was missing I believe.